# Android NFC - Not getting Tag information using Application Record (AAR)

Tags: android, nfc, android-applicationrecord, tag-dispatching

I am trying to read NFC tag (NfcA) when app is in background using Android Application Record (AAR). When Tag is being discovered, my app is getting open although it is not delivering Tag info in an activity.

Also it is alwasy opening Launcher activity and not the one in which Intent filter is added for `NDEF_DISCOVERED`. I have created AAR using `createApplicationRecord()` method.
I tried using both `enableForegroundDispatch()` and `enableReadMode()` approach. Also tried suggestions given in different SO posts like using only AAR in Tag, use URI as mimetype for first record etc.

What could be the issue in this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything could correct this issue, my understanding of the [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/refs/heads/master/src/com/android/nfc/NfcDispatcher.java#592) is that it always uses the AAR to launch the App before it processes any manifest Intent filter.

You could probably work around it by in the Launcher activity in `onCreate` get the Intent and check it for a NFC Tag data and then straight away yourself launch the Activity you want to handle the Intent and pass the Intent along before the launcher does anything else in `onCreate`